# How to get rid of all "weekday words" from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, weekday

Suppose I have the following string (just an example, the real string could contain all weekday words), and I want to use PHP to get rid of all the weekday words and only keep month and date words. How can I do that?

`FRIDAY MAY 23,
Friday May 23,
FRI. May 23,
SATURDAY MAY 24, 
SAT. may 24, 
Saturday May 24, 
Sat. may 24,
Sunday May 25`

Right now I am trying to create an array with all possible values(full words and abbreviations) and execute the str_replace function. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this pattern `(?:sat|sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri)\.?(?:\w*day)?\s?` and case insensitive
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uS4cA6)

Comment: #1 for providing a demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
mon[a-z\.]*\s+|tue[a-z\.]*\s+|wed[a-z\.]*\s+|thu[a-z\.]*\s+|fri[a-z\.]*\s+|sat[a-z\.]*\s+|sun[a-z\.]*\s+
```

with the flags: ig

i - case insensitive
g - global